# How do you unbind specific windows explorer shortcuts

Tags: windows-vista, windows-explorer, windows-registry, hotkeys

Windows Vista (more specifically, explorer) binds win+1, win+2, win+3, etc for its quick-launch bar.  I want to use those key combinations for a different program. There is a registry key(s) to prevent explorer from binding those shortcuts so that I can bind them myself, but I can not remember what it is.

Every search I've tried turns up saying set `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\NoWinKeys`
to 1, but that disables all the shortcuts (win+r, etc) instead of just specific ones.

I did it before on my last computer but I can't remember the specific registry setting.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I finally found it by scouring the registry of one of my old computer.

The registry key I was looking for is
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced\DisabledHotkeys`

If it's not present, create a new Expandable String Value and add any characters you don't want windows explorer to bind.

For example, setting DisabledHotkeys to `12` will prevent explorer from binding  windowskey+1 and windowskey+2

Comment: which character do you type in `DisabledHotkeys` to disable Win+Arrow (whatever arrow)?

Comment: @pataluc This answer is missing information about virtual keys and how to add those. I checked https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731%28v=vs.85%29.aspx and the arrows need 4 characters, all of them non-printable. You need to look up a single arrow (e.g. arrow left has code 25), then right-click the registry value, pick Modify binary data and enter "25 00 00 00" (ignore the four zeroes on the left). Repeat, and in the end you should have 16 pairs of characters.

Comment: @JBert It doesn’t seem possible to disable <kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> that way (i.e. 20 instead of 25).

Comment: Is a restart needed ?   I asume it is required since windows needs a restart for almost everything. But if not, please specify so :)

Comment: @aemonge If something only affects the Explorer, it should be sufficient to log off and log on again.

Comment: This basically works, but some hotkeys cannot be disabled that way, like F (Feedback hub) or G (Xbox game bar), probably because they're not registered by Explorer but other processes.

Comment: @pataluc that registry key has nothing to do with Win+Arrow which is the aero snap feature and has its own setting: [Disabling Winkey+Arrow on Windows 10](https://superuser.com/q/1719448/241386)

Answer (score 0):

I did this with Windows 10... created the `DisabledHostkeys` and added "S". However, that prevented the entire Search function and Search icon from working as well!  Not recommended!