# Disabling three-key snipping tool hotkey via DisabledHotkeys registry value?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-registry, hotkeys, snipping-tool

Windows 10 binds <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to the snipping tool. I want to use that keybind for another program. You can make a new registry key in `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced` called `DisabledHotkeys` with a value of `S` to disable <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, `E` to disable <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> and etc.

But I haven't seen anyone mention how to disable three-key hotkeys and I'm not sure how to even input `SHIFT key` as a value. All I've found is [this thread](https://superuser.com/a/189136/) (Look at comment by JBert) which seems to have found a theoretical way to input `LEFT ARROW key` as a value (To disable <kbd>Win</kbd>+ <kbd>←</kbd> hotkey) but doesn't seem like it worked out as intended for them.

Comment: Maybe try Auto HotKey for this. I have found it better to accept Microsoft Hot Keys and change the third part Apps.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to disable the <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> hotkey in a way I didn't expect it to work. I used the [Virtual-Key code values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes) page from the thread I've linked, found the SHIFT key value of `0x10` from there (Just the number 10 is what we need to remember), then modified the binary data of the `DisabledHotkeys` string to add "10" at the start to look like the image below.

[image]

After that clicked OK and modified the value the usual way, added `S` after the new new symbol that appeared to have the final value look like shown on the image below. Pressed OK, restarted and to my surprise it actually worked and now the <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> hotkey doesn't open anything!

[image]

This has its downsides though: it also disables the <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> hotkey which I thankfully don't use so it isn't a problem for me but could be a problem for some people. It would've also disabled the <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> shortcut if it existed since I believe it disables every key used in the hotkey combination, so that's to note.

Comment: Entering shift (0x10) is unnecessary and has no effect here. An S anywhere in the value of DisabledHotkeys disables all hotkeys bound to the S key, with any set of modifier keys. Modifiers are handled separately of the actual bound key, so entering 0x10 does not, for instance, disable all hotkeys involving Shift.

Answer (score 1):

To unbind <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> from Explorer,
paste the following text into a `.reg` file and double-click it to execute:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced]
"DisabledHotkeys"="S"
```

If you ever wish to undo this, do the same with the following `.reg` file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced]
"DisabledHotkeys"=-
```

Reference :
[How to disable specific global hotkeys in Windows](https://www.ghacks.net/2015/03/22/how-to-disable-specific-global-hotkeys-in-windows/).

Comment: Can confirm this works in Windows 11. Note that it also disables Win+S.